# Get output parameter from procedure Phalconphp

Tags: phalcon

My Code :

```
$item = new Items2;
        $connection = $item->getReadConnection();
        $sql = "CALL `OLViewItemsListViewAllWithCount`('','','',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,'2018-05-15',0,0,10,@aa);";
        $items = new Resultset(null,$robot,$connection->query($sql));
```

i need to get the @aa from this Result as a output parameter

how can i get it ?

---

Need to select out parameters in second query like..

```
$item = new Items2;
        $connection = $item->getReadConnection();
        $sql = "CALL `OLViewItemsListViewAllWithCount`('','','',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,'2018-05-15',0,0,10,@aa);";
        $items = $robot,$connection->query($sql)->fetchAll(\Phalcon\Db::FETCH_ASSOC);;
$sql2 = "SELECT @aa"; 

$aa = $connection->query($sql2)->fetch();

echo $aa['@aa];
```

Comment: Use a multi-query statement?

Comment: Yes, 2 results from this request. how can i get it ?

Comment: fetch()? https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/3237/stored-procedure-in-phalcon